# Use attractor point with a vector to change size of small cubes

Tags: 3d, grasshopper

I'm learning right now [GrassHopper](http://grasshopper3d.com) and I'm in front of a problem.

I'm trying to use the concept of `attractor point` in such way that the size of my elements will be different, according to if I'm close or not from my `attractor-point`.

This is for now, what I managed to do:

[image: For now what I have]

So as you can see, the cube is already generated. What I would like is let say to select the point at the bottom left and the closer I will be from this point, the smallest the cube will be (and reciprocally, if I'm far, the cube is bigger)
Somehow as on this picture:

[image: What we need]

Because I'm learning step by step, I would like to limit myself to only few components. I saw on internet that people managed to perform what I want with only a point, a vector and some multiplication with the shape they want to transform.

[image: Components useable]

The problem with all of this it that, I tried to plug them in many way but none of them is working. The closest I get is that the size of all the cubes where getting smaller/bigger according to a `scalling-factor`, but this not really what I would like to obtain.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok somehow I managed to answer my own question with this schema of pluggin

[image: Schema solution]

And with such schema, you can obtain the final result as follow:

[image: Result]